# What do these sentences in the "The Evil Within" intro mean?

Tags: video-games, the-evil-within

40s: Joseph says: "Some kind of scandal?"

I  did not get what he means. Also,

47s: Joseph says: "It's a possibility. I believe the records were sealed"

What this means exactly? Is he holding a diary? The records are on the diary?

Comment: Just as a reminder, you can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. It looks like you have several questions with unaccepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Some kind of scandal?

He's speaking in an uncertain tone of voice, basically indicating that it's not known exactly what happened, but that it was something that people were talking about, the patients going missing as per one of the Merriam Webster definitions of "[scandal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scandal)".

> Loss of or damage to reputation caused by actual or apparent violation of morality or propriety

### It's a possibility. I believe the records were sealed

This is a response to Joseph being asked if he thinks the past events (the patients going missing) was connected with the current case. He's referring to the [legal records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_sealing), which might have had more details of what happened, but which are not available without a court order. I think he's just holding up his notepad and waving it for emphasis that there is information missing.

> Record sealing is the practice of sealing or, in some cases, destroying court records that would otherwise be publicly accessible as public records. The term is derived from the tradition of placing a seal on specified files or documents that prevents anyone from reviewing the files without receiving a court order. The modern process and requirements to seal a record and the protections it provides vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, and even between civil and criminal cases.

....

> The public policy of record sealing balances the desire to free named citizens from the burdens caused by the information contained in state records while maintaining the state's interest in the preservation of records that may be beneficial to the state or other citizens.

I'm not familiar with the plotline of the game, but this sometimes is done where there are details irrelevant to the case itself, but potentially damaging, say documentation showing that the hospital supervisor was having an affair, or financial records of the hospital. If neither are proven to have a bearing on the case, the records might be sealed so that a reporter couldn't take that information and publish it as its own news. The state preserves that evidence, perhaps because it exculpates one of the people being charged (the supervisor couldn't have been involved with the murder because the hotel records show that he was in a room with his secretary, for example).